# Laravel Multi Auth - Manually Logging In Users

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel package Laravel Multi Auth. How can I manually log in user ?

```
https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native login()

```
$user = User::find($id);

Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: then what results do you have with Auth::login($user);

Comment: which one? the Auth::account()->login($user); or the Auth::login($user);

Comment: Auth::account()->login($user);